# rvmsudo : command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, sudo, ubuntu-10.10

I am following this great post to configure my rails production server on ubuntu 10.10 : [rails production](http://blog.bigrocksoftware.com/2011/01/07/rvm-nginx-passenger-rails-3/)

When I want to execute the command :

`rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`

I get the error : `rvmsudo : command not found`

Can anybody help me ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally performed a new global settings of my server and I installed passenger following carefully the instructions on the official web site [here](http://www.modrails.com/install.html)

Everything works now.

Answer (score 5):

Updating to the latest version helped me:

```
rvm get latest
rvm reload
```

The rvmsudo command was available after that.

Answer (score 0):

That command is part of rvm. Have you installed rvm already? https://rvm.io. Follow the installation instructions carefully. It adds a lot to the login script, so just to be sure to be sure, logout and log back in to make sure it's setup properly. Skip the gemsets for now just to get up and running, then revisit that.